# When I want my threads to share an ArrayList, where do I instantiate the ArrayList, and how do I access it from the main method?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronized

I want to be able to create multiple threads in my main method, have each thread run code to generate certain Objects through calling run() on each, and then have each thread upon completion add these Objects to a shared ArrayList. So right now I have my `class Threader implements Runnable{` and my `public class Processor`, which has my `main` method as the only method. My `main` method creates `i` threads while passing in the relevant arguments I want and then calls `start()` on each of them. In the `start()` method in my `Threader` class I run through some code I wrote, ending with the creation of a custom `Document` object. When the thread has successfully created that object, I want it to be able to add it to a `documents` ArrayList of type `<documents>`.

So I assume I want to make the ArrayList synchronized, but where would I instantiate it so that I can also access it from my `main` method?

Comment: Global variable?

Comment: Store it in a `Singleton`? Try not to set your Virtual Machine on fire.

Comment: Create the `ArrayList` in the "main" method, pass reference of it to each thread you create. *"I assume I want to make the ArrayList synchronized"* - That's correct, `ArrayList` is NOT thread safe.  You could use something like [`Collections.synchronuzedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) which will allow you to make a `List` thread safe (wraps in a thread safe proxy), but then you'd have to make use `List` instead of `ArrayList` as you base requirement (remember `ArrayList` implements `List`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer So if my synchronizedList was called `documents`, every time I would create a new thread, I write it as `Thread thread1 = new Thread(documents)`, then anything I add to `documents` from any thread will be added to my one and only List in the main method?

Comment: @user2709168 In theory, yes. So long as they all write the same reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a synchronized `List` in your `main` method then you can pass it to the threads created by the `main` method. Using an interface like `List` rather than a concrete class like `ArrayList` as the parameter in your method can help you to decouple the `Threader` to a concrete class.

In the `main` method, you can create a `ArrayList` and then use `Collections.synchronuzedList` to convert it to a synchronized `List`.

Comment: I'd like to add that doing just this gave me a ConcurrentModificationException. I had to add a short delay in between the creation of each thread to solve this via `Thread.sleep()`.

Answer (score 1):

Make the List a static field in your Threader class or instantiate it in main and pass it to each thread. Either way you probably want to consider using a synchronized collection or you'd have to implement your own synchronous methods for add, get, ect...